# Getting values from master page to child page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, master-pages

I have a master page `masterpage.master` in which i have stored a value in a variable that is

```
string Name = (string)(Session["myName"]);
```

Now i want to use the value which is in "Name" into the child pages of  `masterpage.master`  but without using session on every page. Can I achieve that? 
If yes..then please tell.

I am using `c#` and `ASP.net` webforms

Comment: passing data between web user control page and master page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028937/how-can-i-get-the-parent-page-from-a-user-control-in-an-asp-net-website-not-web/54412216#54412216

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
   // Master Page File (Storing the value in label)
    string Name = (string)(Session["myName"]);
    lblmsg.Text= name;

   // cs File
    Label str = Master.FindControl("lblmsg") as Label;
    TextBox10.Text = str.Text ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put `Name` in a control i.e. `TextBox` on `MasterPage` and find that in content pages like this.

```
// On Master page
TextBox mastertxt = (TextBox) Master.FindControl("txtMaster");

// On Content Pages
lblContent.Text = mastertxt.Text;
```

For more details on it check this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can access your [masterpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) from current page and cast it to your class type:

```
MyMasterPage master = Master as MyMasterPage;
var value = master.NeededProperity;
```

Looks like [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) in comments:

Public property is a good way to go, but one would have to put the MasterType directive in every content page (the .aspx file). If content pages extend a base class (which extends Page), then the same strong typing can be done in the base class CodeBehind. For example:

```
    // MySiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPagepublic

 string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return MessageContent.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            MessageContent.Text = value;
        }
    }

    // MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    MySiteMaster masterPage = Master as MySiteMaster;
    masterPage.Message = "Message from content page";
```

MessageContent is a control on the master page. The MyPage class could expose Message as its own property or allow derived classes to access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Readonly Property to your Master Page

```
public string MyName
{
    get { return (string)(Session["myName"]); }
}
```

Add this code after your page declaration of content page (change the Master Page file name & path accordingly )

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Site.master" %>
```

Then you can access your property from the content page

```
var MyNameFromMaster = Master.MyName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the masterpagetype directives in your aspx page like below

```
  <%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/Site.master"%>
```

Now you can access the variables of master page using "Master.[VariableName]"