# Call parent page function from user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a Default.aspx page and I am using a usercontrol in it. On some condition in usercontrol.cs I have to invoke a function present in Default.aspx.cs page (i.e parent page of user control). Please help and tell me the way to do this task.

Comment: [This Will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623136/calling-a-method-in-parent-page-from-user-control?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the `Page` property to the actual type:

```
var def = this.Page as _Default;
if(def != null)
{
    def.FunctionName();
}
```

the method must be public:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void FunctionName()
    { 

    }
}
```

But note that this is not best-practise since you are hard-linking the `UserControl` with a `Page`. Normally one purpose of a UserControl is reusability. Not anymore here. The best way to communicate from a `UserControl` with it's page is using a custom event which can be handled by the page.

[**Mastering Page-UserControl Communication - event driven communication**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to the user control:

```
public event EventHandler SpecialCondition;
```

Raise this event inside your user control when the condition is met:

```
private void RaiseSpecialCondition()
{
    if (SpecialCondition != null) // If nobody subscribed to the event, it will be null.
        SpecialCondition(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then in your page containing the user control, listen for the event:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        this.UserControl1.OnSpecialCondition += HandleSpecialCondition;
    }

    public void HandleSpecialCondition(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your handler here.
    }
}
```

You can change the `EventArgs` to something more useful to pass values around, if required.

Answer (score 0):

parent.aspx.cs

```
public void DisplayMsg(string message)
{
    if (message == "" || message == null) message = "Default Message";
    Response.Write(message);
}
```

To Call function of parent Page from user control use the following:
UserControl.ascx.cs

```
 this.Page.GetType().InvokeMember("DisplayMsg", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, new object[] { "My Message" });
```

This works fine for me..

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 MyAspxClassName aspxobj= new MyUserControlClassName();
    aspxobj.YourMethod(param);
```

Comment: Are you kidding? Apart from the fact that a `UserControl` is not a `Page`, using a constructor to create a page(or `UserControl`) will not work if you want to access controls on that `Page` or `UserControl` since this instance is not created from ASP.NET through a page's lifecycle.