# How to call method from Dynamically Added UserControls with Delegate

Tags: asp.net, delegates

I have a problem with user control. I cannot call method from usercontrol.
My default.aspx are contains Update panel. Because I don't want repostback page.

My default.aspx page is:

```
public partial class Page_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load();
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        if (Session["User"] == null)
        {
            ApplicationController.Controls.Add(new UserControl().LoadControl("View/Public/Login.ascx"));
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationController.Controls.Add(new UserControl().LoadControl("View/Public/Welcome.ascx"));
        }
    } 
}
```

and Dynamically Added UserControls is:

```
public partial class View_Public_Login : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnAssetsGiris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = new Kys.Dbo.Assets.user()
        {
            UserId = txtEmail.Text.Trim(),
            Pwd = txtPwd.Text.Trim()
        }.Login();

        if (user != null)
        {
            Session["User"] = user;
        }
    }
}
```

How to call `Load()` method from user control?

Comment: Create an event handler, let your `default.aspx` page register to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You can send me any example?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623136/calling-a-method-in-parent-page-from-user-control

Comment: Thanks, but i have not added by dragging control. i have added dynamically on the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
var usercontrol = (View_Public_Login ).LoadControl("View/Public/Login.ascx");
usercontrol.Load()....
ApplicationController.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better.