# Calling a method in parent page from a user control residing inside a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I followed a number of other question to try to solve this problem but they don't seem to apply to my case. [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623136/calling-a-method-in-parent-page-from-user-control).

In my case, an instance of the user control is being loaded multiple times in a repeater and I am suspecting this has something to do with the problem I have.

I am attaching the event to each instance of the user control using this method.

```
  protected void rptPosts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      DataRowView MyRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
      Post MyPost = (Post)e.Item.FindControl("Post");

      MyPost.UserControlButtonClicked += new EventHandler(MyPost_UserControlButtonClicked);

      MyPost.LoadPost(MyRow);
    }
  }

  private void MyPost_UserControlButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // reload repeater items
  }
```

Inside the user control code behind I put this code:

```
  public event EventHandler UserControlButtonClicked;

  private void OnUserControlButtonClick()
  {
    if (UserControlButtonClicked != null)
    {
      UserControlButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
```

And in the button inside the user control (that is supposed to trigger the page method) I put this:

```
  protected void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Code to delete record //

    OnUserControlButtonClick();
  }
```

The problem seems to be that `if (UserControlButtonClicked != null)` seems to always return false and therefore `UserControlButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);` is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook the event up on OnItemCreated. Othervise if you post the page it will be gone. So I would expect that it will look something like this:

```
protected void rptPosts_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Post MyPost = (Post)e.Item.FindControl("Post");
        MyPost.UserControlButtonClicked += new EventHandler(MyPost_UserControlButtonClicked);
    }
}
```

And then in ItemDataBound you do not really need to hook the event up. So it will look like this:

```
protected void rptPosts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      DataRowView MyRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
      Post MyPost = (Post)e.Item.FindControl("Post");
      MyPost.LoadPost(MyRow);
    }
}
```

In ItemDataBound you still need to load the post. I would not suggest doing that in ItemCreated. Because that would mean that you will load the posts every time you create the item. Which is not what you want

Reference:

- [Repeater.ItemCreated Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Osprey : No problem. Glad to help