# How to set the background color for a user control button? and how to pass in parameters to its event handler?

Tags: c#, css, webforms

I created a user control for a button because I will be needing to use it multiple times in the application.

```
<td class = "center" colspan = "4"><uc:Instructions ID="Instructions" runat="server" />
```

I have this in the ascx file of the button

```
<asp:Button ID ="btnInstrs" Text ="Instructions" runat ="server" CssClass ="buttonGreen" OnClick ="btnInstrs_onClick"/>
```

This is the code behind for the user-control

```
    protected void btnInstrs_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void setColorGreen()
{
    btnInstrs.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

I have this as the CSS

```
.buttonGreen
{
background-color: green;
}
```

So far I have this in the code behind in one of the pages I will be needing this button

```
 Instructions.setColorGreen();
```

The setColorGreen method is changing the background color to green when I call it. Any idea why using just the CSS isn't doing the job?

Now to my main question.

I want to return some instructions as a popup and some text on the page when the button is clicked. to get those instructions I will need an itemID to look in the DB and get the instructions So if I was doing everything in the source page. In the event handler I would make a D.B call for the item ID and find the instructions and display but because I want to do it using the user control I don't know how to pass in the itemID or anything else as the parameter into the user control event handler.

Any advise as to how I could code the event handler so I can re-use it in different pages to get the instructions(for an itemID) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Calling a method in parent page from user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623136/calling-a-method-in-parent-page-from-user-control)

This answers my second question. Create an event for the user control when clicked. Handle the event in the source page when exposed.

I can use my itemID in the event handler to make necessary database calls and retrieve information and publish the instructions.

I do the same thing for any other pages required.

Still did not understand why CSS isn't setting the background color of the button to Green.